# WinGrid column IntegerWithSpin starting value

Tags: ultrawingrid

Below is my C# code:

```
grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[11].Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.IntegerWithSpin;

grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[11].MaskInput = "nnn";

grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[11].MinValue = -99;

grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[11].MaxValue = 99;
```

The problem here is that on the application, when I press the "UP" arrow to increase the number, it always starts from -99 but I would like it to start from 0.

Meaning when I press the "UP" arrow the value in the column cell should be 1 instead of -98.

Do anyone know how I could solve this problem?

Comment: Using the code above with the `.DataSource` property set to a `BindingList` of an object that has an integer property, I was no able to reproduce the behavior described. It started at 0 as expected (the integer property was left uninitialized, so its value was 0 by default). You could try the `.DefaultValue` property perhaps.